# IDsObjectPicker fails on the latest Windows 10 updates

Tags: c++, active-directory, x86

I've had some Active Directory "Select Users or Groups" code based on IDsObjectPicker working for years but suddenly it has stopped working on the latest Windows 10 updates. The Select User dialog opens correctly but when clicking "Check names" or "Advanced > Find Now" I get an error (Unspecified error):

[image]

The application is a 32 bit C++ MFC based application. If I run it as Administrator it works. I found a C# sample that works but without running as Administrator.

I found an old sample on Code Project that has the same problem:
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/6307/using-the-windows-2000-xp-object-selection-dialog

Any ideas?